# How much can throughput of high throughput fizzbuzz be exceeded with special processor?

Tags: microcontroller, performance

[A popular answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236630) on code golf stack exchange achieves 52 Gbps on fizzbuzz program.

I am curious if the limits of throughput can be exceeded by using specialised hardware, processor, co-processor.

How would one approach this problem and is there any prior work on something similar?

Comment: There's always a bottleneck. In this case, according to the author of the post you yourself linked, the bottleneck is L2 write speed. So, get a processor with faster L2.

Comment: `throughput` is some thing *fizzbuzz* doesn't have for lack of input. How exactly would the output be represented? "Where would it go to"?

Comment: @greybeard in the setting I am thinking of, keeping a display as output target would not make sense as even in the original question, I think the 50Gbps solution exceeds the display refresh rate by many orders.

Can we think of the output as an uncompressed digital stream.. uncompressed means all digits and characters are represented by their ascii code, and stream means any output interface. For example, The maximum speed of fiber optic cable can be up to 100Gbps. So we can think of that as the output?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can't be definitively answered. It's definitely possible to improve performance with specialized hardware. A case study here is [Bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) mining, where specialized [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit)s [have been developed](https://www.bitmain.com/). The cost will simply exponentially increase with target performance. As each new bottleneck or physical barrier is encountered, the complexity and cost to remove the barrier will be higher and higher. For Bitcoin there is a moving equilibrium where implementation cost equals revenue. For [fizzbuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) there's no revenue, so it just depends how much money you want to throw away at it.

The author of the post you linked has indicated that the bottleneck in that implementation is [L2 cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) write speed. So the first thing to throw at this implementation would be a faster L2 cache.